# How to connect Aurora by SDK : ExecuteStatementCommand in Provisioned Aurora

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-aurora

I try to connect `Provisioned Aurora`(not the serverless Aurora),I refer to this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-rds-data/classes/executestatementcommand.html) and after several search,I set up following.

I noticed that `ExecuteStatementCommand` may be restricted to `Aurora serverless`
It use `Data API`?

```
import { captureAWSv3Client } from 'aws-xray-sdk-core';
import { ExecuteStatementCommand, RDSDataClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-rds-data';

  getUser: async (parent,_,context) =>{
        const client = captureAWSv3Client(new RDSDataClient({}));
          const cmd = new ExecuteStatementCommand({
              resourceArn: process.env.CLUSTER_ARN,
              secretArn: process.env.SECRET_ARN,
              database: 'jp_icqa',
              sql: `select * from User`,
          });

          try{
              const data = await client.send(cmd);
              console.log('data',data);
              return data.records
          } catch (error){
              console.error(error);


              throw new Error('Failed fetching data to jp_icqa Aurora');
          } finally {

          }
```

So I am searching how to connect `Provisioned Aurora`. Are there any document about it ?
If someone know this,will you please let me know
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The RDS Data Client currently only works with serverless Aurora. You can't use that with provisioned Aurora. You have to connect using a standard MySQL or PostgreSQL database client.